# user interface to get xml element's data in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying develop a website which provide user interface to generate `XML` file. The user interface will ask for data required in various `XML` elements. The generate `XML` should follow `DTD` specifications.

So here is what I did.

1. I converted `DTD` to `XSD`.
2. I created `C#` class using xsd.exe tool.

Now my question is how can I generate dynamic input boxes on the webpage that will ask for required element data from the C# class I created.

I need some way to know the required and optional elements and their data type and attribute and all from the C# class I created.

i hope you get what i am asking, thanks for looking.

Comment: Can you show us the generated C# class? It will be easier to explain using your own classes.

Comment: it is a client DTD and too big class is generated (222kb) so can not provide here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that most of the required/optional semantics from the xsd are lost in the classes generated with xsd.exe. You basically have 2 (+1 edited later ) options:

1. Use reflection over your generated types to render UI elements for each property. You'll have to manually manage/define databindings
2. Drop the xsd.exe classes and generate your UI elements by traversing the xsd itself. That way you get way more info about optional/nullable elements, cardinality etc. Construct your resulting xml by hand (use XDocument) from your UI inputs.
3. The hybrid approach: Reflect over generated classes for structure (easier traversal logic. no need to handle external includes etc). Go to the xsd for the additional info (You'll need to somehow figure out where in the xsd to find your needed definitions that map to the current property)

Either way you choose this will not be a trivial task and you'll need a lot of work to make it happen. And if we're going in the realm of XSD choice elements etc. you'll soon figure out that no straight forward UI can cover all the possible scenarios

Comment: thank you very much so if i choose to generate input box by traversing XSD it self can you suggest like how do i get required and option elements and its data type from XSD. is there any methods available in built in xml classes for C#.

Comment: well an Xsd is just and xml so you would need to look for the related attributes and read their values. Use XDocument for this as well. Also check XmlSchema class for more xsd like semantics.

Comment: as per my knowledge DTD is following general mark up so with C# we can not parse DTD it self. so parsing xsd is the only option or i can parse DTD as well if you know some way ?

Comment: i was refering on parsing XSD as well. no idea on DTDs (is anyone using them still in 2014 ? :P)

Comment: ok i searched for getting node info from XSD and found some solution like create XML for each possible case and than traverse is. this is not possible with me as i have more than 65 cases. i will search further and keep this thread updated.